# CSS Responsive Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

For this site: http://www.insidemarketblog.com - you can see that when u resize the window to tablet size, the sidebar goes to the bottom, but the main content retains it's size.

What I want to do is that when the window is resized and sidebar goes below, the main content fills the entire window (no more black space).  Resize this for an example: http://www.quicksprout.com/blog/

I thought I set up  the @media correctly, but it's not working.  Any ideas?

CSS:

```
   /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        .wrap {max-width: 100%}
           .grt {font-size: 100%;}
        }

    /* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .wrap {max-width: 98%;}
     .grt {font-size: 87.5%; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px;}
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<div id="post-1" class="post_box grt top" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemscope="">
<div id="comments">
<div class="prev_next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `max-width:532px;` from line 95 of your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `max-width:532px;` property from here:

```
.container, .landing .container {
width: auto;
max-width: 532px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move a style to the appropriate media query block:

```
@media all and (max-width: 532px){
   .container, .landing .container{width:auto;max-width:532px}
}
```